# Odd result in Google Sheets calculation

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am editing an existing spreadsheet in Google Drive and the formula below is giving me an answer I cannot figure out.

```
=if(isBlank({H6}),ifError(1/0),(( ArrayFormula( ROUND((P6*1.2)))-0.05)))
```

where H6 is text, P6 is the value `7.95`.

The result is `9.95`, but I was expecting `9.49`

Can anyone explain why? Is it something to do with `{}` around H6?

Answer (score 0):

- it has nothing to do with **`{}`** brackets - the unexpected output is caused by **`ROUND`** formula which has an unspecified 2nd parameter:

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK({H6}), IFERROR(1/0), ((ARRAYFORMULA(ROUND((P6*1.2), 2))-0.05)))
  ```
- which btw has a lot of unneccessary stuff so:

  ```
  =IFERROR(IF(LEN(H6), ROUND((P6*1.2), 2)-0.05, ))
  ```

  [image: 0]